# How to get the index of the ACTIVE CHILD div of my container with jQuery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="active">
      <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to write such a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) without parameters to get it's (`0`-based) index amongst siblings, like this:

```
var index = $("#container .active").index();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DQAgH/).  For your example markup, it would be `0`.

Comment: `$("#container .active")` is not necessarily a **child** element

Comment: @fms - can you explain what you mean a bit more? I can only go by the information given...

Comment: I've updated the html so that `$("#container .active")` will fail.

Comment: `$("#container .active")` will also select the non-child element `div.active`,right?

Comment: @fms - well, it'll find the first...so it'll still be correct, if you want only *direct* children though, use `>`, like this: `$("#container > .active")`